# An exercise where Kronecker's Lemma cannot be comfortably used.

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I am working an exercise stated as follows:

> Let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}$ for independent random variable $(Y_{k})$ such that $Var(Y_{k})<B<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}Y_{k}=0$ for all $k$. Show that $$\dfrac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n(\log n)^{1+\epsilon}}}\longrightarrow 0\ \text{a.s.}$$

My idea was to use Krnonecher's lemma that if $0<a_{n}\nearrow\infty$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}/a_{n}<\infty$, then $a_{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\longrightarrow 0$ a.s.

So we replace $a_{n}=\sqrt{n(\log n)^{1+\epsilon}}$ which clearly $\nearrow \infty$, and replace $X_{k}=Y_{k}$, it then reminds to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{Y_{k}}{a_{k}}<\infty.$$ To show this, my idea was to use Kolmogorov's 1 series.

Firstly, $\mathbb{E}Y_{k}/a_{k}=0$ and $Var(Y_{k}/a_{k})\leq B/a_{k}^{2}.$

**However, the problem arose when I tried to compute the infinite sum of variance.**

You could see the problem here is that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}Var(Y_{k}/a_{k})\leq B\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k(\log k)^{1+\epsilon}},$$ but the summand has singularity at $k=1$, so we can only say this sum is finite if we start at $k=2$. But then we lost the power to use Kolmogorov.

**On the other hand,** we are also not satisfying the condition that $a_{n}>0$, since $a_{1}=0$, which is exactly what causes us the problem.

Is there anyway for me to modify a little bit so that my proof can go through?

It is perfectly fine if you point out that this exercise is not doable :)

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

As Kabo Murphy pointed out, we can modify the sequence a little bit without affecting the limit. However, we do not need to modify $Y_{k}$ as it is not where our problem comes from.

We only need to set $a_{1}$ to be anything between $0$ and $a_{2}$, that is $0<a_{1}\leq a_{2}$, so that $a_{n}$ is a positive increasing sequence. And that's it, since $a_{1}$ then will not create $0$ term in the infinite sum of variance, so we just split the sum into $k=1$, and $k\geq 2$, which definitely converges.

Then the result follows from Kronecker's lemma, even though $a_{1}$ does not admit the general formula of $a_{n}$ for $n\geq 2$, since we take $n\longrightarrow\infty$ (so $a_{1}$ is not really important).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term $k=1$ can easily be ignored (without changing the $a_n$'s). Let $Y_1'=0$ and $Y_i'=Y_i$ for  $i >1$. If you have shown that the result holds for this new sequence you get it for the original sequence by the simple fact that $\frac 1 {\sqrt {n(\log n)^{1+\epsilon}}} \to 0$.

Comment: if we do your modification, for $k=1$ term, we would have $0/0$, since $a_{1}=0$. what should I do here?

Comment: I think we need to modify $a_{n}$ otherwise $a_{1}=0$ so we cannot apply Kronecker....

Comment: @JacobsonRadical The first term does not affect the final result. Take $a_1=1$ and define $a_n$ the way you have defined for $n>1$. Then apply your argument to prove that the result hods for $(Y_n')$. At the end go to $(Y_n)$.

Comment: you are right. I will just define $a_{1}$ to be anything less than $a_{2}$ but not $0$, to ensure the $(a_{n})$ is an increasing sequence.